# Unable to append data to parquet [FileAlreadyExists exception]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, append, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm trying append data from data frame to existing parquet file with command:

```
dfModified
  .write
  .mode("append")
  .parquet("/home/hduser/s_s_c/fadpd/fadpd.parquet")
```

But I'm keep getting this kind of exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory: file:/home/hduser/s_s_c/fadpd/fadpd.parquet
```

Also, I set *spark.speculation* at the beginning on **false**. 
Does anyone have an idea where am I mistaking? Thank you for help and time!

Comment: I believe Spark append mode give you the option to add additional parquet files to an exiting directory, rather than actually append additional data to an existing parquet file.

If you remove the name of the parquet file (fadpd.parquet) I believe your code will work.

Comment: You have absolutely right here and the code will work if I remove `fadpd.parquet`. But, imagine by the time you will updating/inserting or something like that for couple thousand times, even million later. Partitions will gone over 500, you will have to make union of thousand parquet files. I don't think that one will be efficient. You do? Does it make sense for making new parquet file for every  update or insert?

Comment: Generally a large number of small files will have a very significant negative influence on performance. 

The most straight forward approaches for dealing with this kind of problem are: 
1. In streaming applications you may buffer the data until it reaches a certain size and only then spill it to output.
2. In Batch applications you may recognize existence of small files, and read them to memory + union them to new output before writing to output
3. In Both cases you may use an additional merger process that will scan the directory and create larger files once in a while

Comment: The "right" approach is as always depends on many variables that are specific to your use case like application type, how often you write the data to output, what is the estimated throughput etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who is trying to append data in parquet file. You **can't** append parquet file. You need to recreate new one and when you are querying, you need to query all of them :)